# How do I change the default file manager in Cinnamon Arch?

Tags: arch-linux, cinnamon, zip, file-manager

I'm a new Arch user, and I have tried to take a few looks around for an answer to this, but most responses point vaguely to the solution rather than anything that goes step-by-step for this. Even on here. But to cut to the chase, I wish to change from Nemo to Index if that is possible. But if there is any file manager than can extract zip files easily, that is better for me.